# Android Device chooser does not offer real Galaxy tab 10.1 device

Tags: android

Running eclipse + android sdk on Windows XP
Have got "hello Android" application running in emulator OK.
Want it to run on Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1.
Android Device chooser does not see real device.
Have install usb drivers on XP from Samsung.
XP device manager shows: Samsung Mobile USB Modem, Samsung Android ADB Interface. Samsung Mobile USB Composite Device.
On Tab have enabled USB debuging.
Have run 'adb devices' and it shows no devices.

Any help greatly appreciated in progressing this next step of my learning the android environment.

Comment: What's your question? Listing off what is seems like you've done isn't really helpful....

Comment: Try "adb kill-server" and then "adb devices". Sometimes that helps me when no devices show up. And as AedonEtLIRA stated you might want to rephrase your post to include a question.

Comment: Sorry that the question was not obvious. The Title says it does not offer the tab as a real device.  The text said 'Want it to run on Samsun Galaxy tab 10.1.  So perhaps wording it another way how do I get Galaxy tab 10.1 to appear as a real device to target the app. I listed what I had done based upon reading many other posts.  Anyway thanks to replies and I will try.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA Listing off what you have tried so far *is* helpful. It's just more helpful if that list comes with a specific question at the end.

Comment: @glorifiedHacker - Point. I should have phrased it as such. I appologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Call 'adb kill-server' or restart Eclipse.
- Some phones also need to have the phone set to 'disk drive' mode, so check to see if there is an option for that on the phone.
- Ensure the connection from the phone/computer is good (most phones will charge when plugged in)
- Restart the computer after installing drivers, as some drivers need this.
- Make sure your Android SDK is up-to-date as the Galaxy Tab is relatively new.

Comment: I don't think eclipse would need updated, Android's SDK maybe.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant! Whoops.

Comment: Well in the words of the 'IT Crowd' "have you tried switching it off and on again" appears to have worked.  So it appears that "Restart the computer after installing drivers, as some drivers need this." was the solution.  Many thanks to all.

Comment: I can't speak for all versions of Windows, but I've never installed a driver on XP and *not* had to restart.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I need to read a little more carefully. I was going to suggest that you enable "USB debugging", but now I see that you have already done that. Have you followed all of the other steps that Google recommends in [Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)?

Comment: Yes I followed this very carefully. Perhaps it should advise to re-power the PC after installing the drivers as this appears to have been the solution.